# Witharrows or other package to connect equations on different places

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, tikz-arrows, book-design

This MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
    colback=teal!10,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=teal!30,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=#1, 
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt,
    enhanced}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathscr{L}(\Psi(\bar{r},t))=\iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}\mathscr{L}\left(G(\bar{r},\bar{r}',t,t') f(\bar{r}',t')\right) dx'dy'dz'dt'=(\star)
\]
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mybox}{}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(\star)&= \iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}\left(\mathscr{L}(G (\bar{r},\bar{r}',t,t')\right) f(\bar{r}',t') \,dx'dy'dz'dt'=\\
&= \iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}\left(-4\pi \delta(\bar{r} -\bar{r}')\delta(t -t'))\right) f(\bar{r}',t') \,dx'dy'dz'dt'=\\
&= -4\pi \iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}\delta(\bar{r} -\bar{r}')\delta(t -t') f(\bar{r}',t') \,dx'dy'dz'dt'=\\
&=-4\pi f(\bar{r},t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

My question is very simple: is there another elegant way to connect the two equations, separated by a text, where I have used is the symbol `\star`? I had thought of something like this (`witharrows` package),

[image]

but that it would not invade the text between the two equations at the top and that bottom where is the colored box.

Any better suggestions are welcome (and to change my tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
    colback=teal!10,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=teal!30,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=#1, 
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt,
    enhanced}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}


\begin{document}
\[
\mathscr{L}(\Psi(\bar{r},t))=\iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}\mathscr{L}\left(G(\bar{r},\bar{r}',t,t') f(\bar{r}',t')\right) dx'dy'dz'dt'=\tikzmark{start}
\]
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mybox}{}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\tikzmark{stop}&= \iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}\left(\mathscr{L}(G (\bar{r},\bar{r}',t,t')\right) f(\bar{r}',t') \,dx'dy'dz'dt'=\\
&= \iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}\left(-4\pi \delta(\bar{r} -\bar{r}')\delta(t -t'))\right) f(\bar{r}',t') \,dx'dy'dz'dt'=\\
&= -4\pi \iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}\delta(\bar{r} -\bar{r}')\delta(t -t') f(\bar{r}',t') \,dx'dy'dz'dt'=\\
&=-4\pi f(\bar{r},t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{mybox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[->] (pic cs:start) -- ++(0,-0.5) -- ++(-13,0) |- (pic cs:stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I prefer to rewrite the name of the equation as a logical consequence of the explanatory text. And to start this new line with **And so we have:**

In my opinion, if the arrows and other ornaments have the merit of making a pretty decoration, they do not make the demonstrations more explicit or easier to understand.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
    colback=teal!10,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=teal!30,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=#1, 
    sharp corners,
    boxrule=0pt,
    enhanced}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\[
\mathscr{L}(\Psi(\bar{r},t))=\iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}\mathscr{L}\left(G(\bar{r},\bar{r}',t,t') f(\bar{r}',t')\right) dx'dy'dz'dt'
\]
\lipsum[1]


\begin{mybox}{}
And so we have:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\mathscr{L}(\Psi(\bar{r},t))&=  \iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}\left(-4\pi \delta(\bar{r} -\bar{r}')\delta(t -t'))\right) f(\bar{r}',t') \,dx'dy'dz'dt'=\\
&= -4\pi \iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^{4}}\delta(\bar{r} -\bar{r}')\delta(t -t') f(\bar{r}',t') \,dx'dy'dz'dt'=\\
&=-4\pi f(\bar{r},t)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, kind colleague :-) I'm glad you gave me an answer :-). Yours is definitely an alternative that I have appreciated. My best regards.